# Google Analytics: How to compare real-time vs yesterday?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

In the REAL-TIME / Overview page, you can see how much people are currently browsing your site. Although, how do you know if this current value is good or bad? I would like to know how much people were browsing my site the same time the day before, so I would know if I have 5% more or less people.

Also, how would I know if the site is doing it better or worse than 1, 2 or 5 hours before? The REAL-TIME shows the last 30 minutes of per minute page-views, but how do I know if the site is going down or up compared to a few hours before? 30 minutes is not enough.

Is there any add-on to add, custom modification to make, or free/paid service to complement?

Answer (score 0):

**You want to use the standard ("core") reporting**. The dimensions that will help you are (`UI / API`):

- [`Hour / ga:hour`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time&jump=ga_hour): A two-digit hour of the day ranging from 00-23 in the timezone configured for the account. This value is also corrected for daylight savings time. If the timezone follows daylight savings time, there will be an apparent bump in the number of sessions during the changeover hour (e.g., between 1:00 and 2:00) for the day per year when that hour repeats. A corresponding hour with zero sessions will occur at the opposite changeover. (Google Analytics does not track user time more precisely than hours.)
- [`Hour of day / ga:dateHour`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time&jump=ga_datehour): Combined values of ga:date and ga:hour formated as YYYYMMDDHH
- [`Date Hour and Minute / ga:dateHourMinute`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time&jump=ga_datehourminute): Combined values of ga:date, ga:hour and ga:minute formated as YYYYMMDDHHMM
- [`Hour Index / ga:nthHour`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time&jump=ga_nthhour): The index for each hour in the specified date range. The index for the first hour of the first day (i.e., start-date) in the date range is 0, for the next hour 1, and so on

With the `UI` you can add [a secondary dimension to reports](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6175970?hl=en) or [build custom reports](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1151300?hl=en), with the API you can need to build your requests from scratch ([try the explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/), [official API doc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/)).